# BizTalk credential for web service, retrieve the value of ***

Tags: single-sign-on, biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

We have a web service that is called through BizTalk, I am admin of it. The web service requires a credential, the password is masked. The previous developer who configured it has left, without in touch with our vendors.

Is it possible to know the value of the masked password?

We are on BizTalk 2013 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the BizTalk application was installed on the server and there was no post deployment step documented to set the password manually (and instructions as to where the password is stored), then it is likely that the bindings included in the MSI actually contain the password (which you should not do as it is not secure).

If that is the case, then from the command line execute the following, replacing setup.msi with the name of the BizTalk msi and replacing in a `<target_dir>` with where you want the files extracted to go.

```
msiexec /a setup.msi /qb TARGETDIR=C:<target_dir>
```

This will then extract all the DLL's and binding files into a set of folders. Browse through the folders until you find the binding file for that environment and open it and search for password.

Source: [How to extract msu/msp/msi/exe files from the command line](http://www.windowswiki.info/2009/02/19/how-to-extract-msumspmsiexe-files-from-the-command-line/)